# Magnetic path length and permeability relation

Tags: magnetics, flux, core

In a transformer, does increasing the magnetic path length reduce flux and permeability and increase thr reluctance of the core?

If yes, why does the equation of relative permeability of a gapped core show that permeability is increased as you increase the MPL?

Comment: In your second question, do you mean the equation for _effective_ permeability of a gapped core?  Also, when you say increase the MPL, do you mean increasing the length of the core or the gap or both?

Comment: Which equation do you refer to. MPL = magnetic path length?

Comment: I meant increasing the length of both the core and gap by same amount. I would also like an answer for non gapped cores. The equation I am referring to is μe = μr / (1 + ( μr × lg / le))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*In a transformer, increasing the magnetic path length reduces flux and permeability and increases reluctance of the core?*

**True.**

The magnetic path length (MPL) is analogous to the length of a conductor for electrical current - increasing the MPL will increase its reluctance (magnetic 'resistance'). **For a given magneto-motive force (MMF) in ampere-turns** the flux produced will depend upon the value of reluctance in ampere-turns per Weber and so an increase in reluctance will produce a decrease in flux. (See Hopkinson's Law)

Permeability is analogous to 'conductivity' and depends upon the material as well as the path length and cross-sectional area. Increasing reluctance will decrease permeability.

*[In electrical terms if the resistance is increased the conductance is decreased]*

*Why does the equation of relative permeability of a gapped core show that permeability is increased as you increase the MPL?*

**False**

The reason an 'air gap' is used is to prevent the core from saturating. {*n.b. the term 'air gap' also refers to other materials such as nylon that is used to fill the gap.}* In other words you are increasing the reluctance of the circuit and as we have already seen this decreases the permeability.

As you don't show the equation you're referring to I'll just go through the basic theory.

The gap reluctance, Rg, is given by:

```
                        Rg = Lg / (μ0 * Ae)
```

where Lg is gap length, μ0 is the permeability of a vacuum (very similar to value for air) and Ae is the cross sectional area.

The core reluctance, Rc, is

```
                        Rc = Lc / (μ0 * μr * Ac)
```

Where Lc is the magnetic core length,  μr is the relative permittivity of the core material (>>μ0) and Ac is the area of the core.

The total reluctance of the magnetic circuit, Rt, is

```
                Rt =  Lc / (μ0 * μr * Ac)  +  Lg / ( μ0 * Ae)
```

Generally Ae = Ac = A (maintains cross sectional area across gap) so this becomes

```
                 Rt = (1 / ( μ0 * A)) * ( (Lc /  μr) + Lg)
```

If  μr is very large (as in most cases of magnetic core material) it is the length of the airgap, Lg, that dominates the Reluctance value. Reluctance **INCREASES** with air gap length (and MPL) and if you increase Reluctance you **DECREASE** the effective Permeability.

Comment: Thank you for answering. The equation I was referring to was μe = μr / (1 + ( μr × lg / le)). Increasing gap length will lower permeability, all is ok. If you increase MPL (le) permeability will increase too. This is confusing as it should not increase. I would also like to ask about non gapped cores, is there an equation relating permeability and MPL?

Comment: @1p2r3k4t μe=μr/(1+(μr×lg/le)) calculates the effective 'mu' of the core. this is true for a simple magnetic circuit, made out of bulk material, for relative permeability if length core >> length gap, and if µcore >> 1. The effective 'mu' of the circuit **cannot** be greater than μr (Lg = 0 or no air gap). All the equation is saying is that if you have two equal length cores, one with a large air gap and one with a small air gap - the small air gap core will have a larger effective permeability **but it will still be much less than a solid core.** which is exactly what you would expect.

Comment: If you have two cores with different MPL (one is bigger in size), but with the same air gap, which one has bigger permeability? The equation says that the bigger core (bigger MPL) will have increased μe. But increased MPL increases the reluctance, decreases flux and decreases permeability. Isn't this a paradox?

Comment: [link](http://www.learnabout-electronics.org/ac_theory/images/flux-4.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

You asked:

> "In a transformer, increasing the magnetic path length reduces flux
>   and permeability and increases reluctance of the core?"

This is not quite right.  The permeability of a material is a property of that material.  Permeability really only makes sense for a uniform material.  It tells you for a given magnetic field, **H**, what your magnetic flux density, **B**, is.  In other words, \$B = \mu H\$. So if you had a transformer with a core with no air gap and *N* turns of wire with current *I* in that wire and length *l*, your magnetic field will be \$H = \frac{N I}{l}\$.  So if you keep all those things constant but increase *l*, then your magnetic field, ***H***, will decrease.  Because \$\mu\$ is a property of your material, it will remain constant.  So if ***H*** decreases and \$\mu\$ stays the same, it means your flux density, ***B***, will also decrease.  So, keeping all other things the same, if you just increase the magnetic path length, then that will change your flux density.  Assuming uniform cross sectional area, this also means your flux will decrease.

Reluctance is defined as \$R = \frac{N I}{\phi} = \frac{H l}{B a} = \frac{l}{\mu a} \$, where \$\phi\$ is the magnetic flux and a is the cross-sectional area.  Again, if all other things remain the same, than an increase in path length results in an increase in reluctance.

So, to restate: An increase in path length of a core of a transformer without an air gap will result in a decreased magnetic field, ***H***, decreased flux density, ***B***, decreased flux, \$\phi\$, and increased reluctance.  However, permeability of the material stays the same.

Effective permeability is a shortcut that is sometimes used to make calculations easier.  Essentially it takes a core with a gap in it and says "What would be the equivalent value of \$\mu\$ if this core had no gap?"  This allows a person (by using the equations above) to quickly find the magnetic flux through the core by just knowing length, cross-sectional area, number of turns and current.  It's a slight shortcut that lets you skip calculating the core reluctance, the air gap reluctance, adding them together, and then calculating flux.

Notice that if you know the reluctance of the core and the air gap individually, you can add them together to get an effective reluctance and from that, if you multiply by cross-sectional area and divide by total length, you will get the effective permeability.  Here are the equations:

$$
R_{core} = \frac{l_{core}}{\mu_{core} a}
$$

$$
R_{gap} = \frac{l_{gap}}{\mu_{gap} a}
$$

$$
R_{eq} = R_{core} + R_{gap} = \frac{1}{a} (\frac{l_{core}}{\mu_{core}} + \frac{l_{gap}}{\mu_{gap}})
$$

$$
\mu_{eq} = \frac{l_{eq}}{R_{eq} a} = \frac{l_{core} + l_{gap}}{R_{eq} a}
$$

And if you work out the math, that last equation comes out to:

$$
\mu_{eq} = \frac{\mu_{core} \mu_{gap} l_{core}}{l_{core} \mu_{gap} + l_{gap} \mu_{core}}
$$

Now, based on that last equation, you can see that if you increase the length of the core, the effective permeability is going to increase.  However, if you increase the air gap, the effective permeability will decrease.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does the equation of relative permeability of a gapped core show
>   that permeability is increased as you increase the MPL?

The permeability of the raw material used in ferrite is called initial permeability, \$\mu_i\$.

When ferrite is "molded" into a shape and gaps introduced, the permeability is then called effective permeability, \$\mu_e\$.

The formula you have is \$\mu_e = \frac{\mu_r}{1+(\mu_r\frac{l_g}{l_e})}\$ where \$\mu_r\$ is relative permeability which can be taken to mean the same as \$\mu_i\$.

Quite simply, effective permeability increases if the gap remains constant but the length of the magnetic path increases. Why? Because the gap becomes smaller relative to the magnetic path length. Use the formula, do the math.

It's nothing to do with the physics (\$\mu_r\$ or \$\mu_i\$) but to do with the effective permeability.

> In a transformer, increasing the magnetic path length reduces flux and
>   permeability and increases reluctance of the core?

YES because magnetic flux is the by-product of magnetic field strength, H and H is purely determined by number of turns, current in the turns and magnetic path length.

Comment: If you have 2 toroidal cores from say electrical steel, the first one has twice the diameter of the second one (2x MPL). Which one has more permeability in the case of no gap existing and in the case of 1mm gap in both of them?